# Primefaces: Hide/Show exact filter in datatable

Tags: primefaces

I am creating a dataTable with filters where the filters can be displayed/hidden using a selectBooleanButton. I am able to hide the text filters, but the select box for 'exact' filter does not hide. Code is given below. I would appreciate any help.

```
<p:dataTable id="orgs" var="id" widgetVar="idTable"
value="#{orgList.ids}" rows="10"
rowKey="#{id.idPk}"
paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top" 
selectionMode="single" 
selection="#{orgList.selectedOrg}"
filteredValue="#{orgList.filteredValues}"
>

<f:facet name="header">
    <p:toolbar id="orgListToolbar">
        <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
            <p:selectBooleanButton value="#{orgList.showFilter}" onIcon="myfilter" offIcon="ui-icon-minusthick" onLabel="F" offLabel="F">
                <p:ajax update="orgs" oncomplete="idTable.clearFilters()"/>
            </p:selectBooleanButton>
        </p:toolbarGroup>
    </p:toolbar>
</f:facet>


<p:column sortBy="#{id.id}" headerText="Id" filterBy="#{id.id}" filterStyle="#{orgList.showFilter?'':'display: none; visibility: hidden;'}">
    <h:outputText value="#{id.id}" />
</p:column>
<p:column sortBy="#{id.idCls.clsName}" headerText="Id Type"             
        filterBy="#{id.idCls.clsName}" filterMatchMode="exact" filterOptions="#{commonLists.selectItemIdClses}" 
        filterStyle="#{orgList.showFilter?'':'display: none; visibility: hidden;'}" >
    <h:outputText value="#{id.idCls.clsName}" />
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Primefaces overrides your `filterStyle`

You can do the following :

In your custom css file add the following (`id` is your table id)

```
#id .ui-column-filter{
 display:none;
}
```

make sure you include your css in the end... (You can load the css in the body) like this

```
<h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="myCssFile.css" target="head" />
```

Note that `display: none;` is enough , no need for the `visibility: hidden;` at all

---

In order to hide / show the filters you can use jQuery `.hide()` / `.show()` functions with the proper selectos

For example :

```
$("#form\\:dataTable th select").hide();//.show

$("#form\\:dataTable th input").hide();//.show
```

Check it in [DataTable - Filtering](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf;jsessionid=5417A2CC639003EB068647742D7EFD0F) (in console of your browser developer tools)

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the response. I am trying to implement a toggle button to show/hide the filters. So your solution may not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

to hide filter from column header in jsf datatable include

filterStyle="display : none"

it will hide the filter column

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is define own style and override the value with !important.

```
        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-column-filter{
                display:none !important;
            }
        </style>
```